# Case sensitivity in SQL XML member?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-sensitive

I'm working on a stored procedure and I came across a small section in which a member name `value` appears to be case sensitive:

```
SELECT @Property1 = CONVERT(INT, C.value('(*:NodeName)[1]','INT'))
FROM @XML.nodes('/*') AS T(C)
```

When I updated `value` to be `Value` it gave me the following error:

> "Value" is not a valid function, property, or field.

The same error occurrs if I change `@XML.nodes` to `@XML.Nodes`.

---

Why is this error occurring?

I assume it's because of how the object was defined, but I thought SQL was not case sensitive.

Comment: In regards to the close vote, this question was not a typo, but a complete disregard for casing as a whole. In this particular case, I'm asking why the change matters, I know what caused the problem, I want to know why it cased the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's specifically XQUERY that is case sensitive. `xml` objects have no `Value` function, it's `value`, just likes like have no `Nodes` or `NODES` function, it's `nodes`.

This is confirmed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) as well:

> ## XQuery Language Reference (SQL Server)
>
> Transact-SQL supports a subset of the XQuery language that is used for querying the xml data type. This XQuery implementation is aligned with the July 2004 Working Draft of XQuery. The language is under development by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C), with the participation of all major database vendors and also Microsoft. Because the W3C specifications may undergo future revisions before becoming a W3C recommendation, this implementation may be different from the final recommendation. This topic outlines the semantics and syntax of the subset of XQuery that is supported in SQL Server.
>
> For more information, see the W3C [XQuery 1.0 Language Specification](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=48846).

And the above Language Specification goes on to state:

> #### 2 Basics
>
> ...
>
> Like XML, **XQuery is a case-sensitive language**. Keywords in XQuery use lower-case characters and are not reserved—that is, names in XQuery expressions are allowed to be the same as language keywords—except for the list of reserved function-names in [A.3 Reserved Function Names](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-xquery-20040723/#id-reserved-fn-names).

Emphasis mine in the final paragraph.